# .EXE VIDEO CONVERT TO MP4

Tags: video, video-editor, mp4, conversion

I have a video that extension is .exe. I try to open this file in Windows but I can't. I try to convert this file to mp4 but again return empty file. How can I open .exe video?

Answer (score 1):

Some things to try:

First just change the filename from "example.exe" to "example.mp4" and then try to open it in a standard video player.  If the file is actually a video format with just a different file name extention then it might play fine.

Secondly, download and install Format Factory - http://www.pcfreetime.com - and try to convert the file into an MP4 file or something.  Format Factory works with a massive range of file formats and has some really good failover routines.  If it can't open the file then it's 99.99% certain that it's not a video file.

If neither work and you are certain that this is a video file then it probably means whoever created it embedded the file so that running the .exe actually extracted and placed the real video somewhere.  At this point do some standard troubleshooting:

- Can you contact the owner / creator and find out how to run it properly?
- Can you right click, properties and run set to run as administrator, or run in compatibility mode for a different version of windows?
- if it runs ok, what happens?  Check your desktop / documents / video folders afterwards to make sure the video hasn't been extracted elsewhere?

otherwise we need more information to be of any help to you.  Where did the file come from, how did it get into a .exe container, what are you expecting of it etc?

Comment: OMG.  .EXE is an executable file.  If a file is named AwesomeClickBaitMovieTitle.exe, there’s an excellent chance it’s a virus.

Comment: I know.  I tried to answer the question assuming the OP knew what was going on.